# iOS force thermal throttling

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, throttling

In our app we have a CPU intensive algorithm that we've had difficulties assessing quality from our production logs.  Recently we've added thermal throttling (normal, serious, and critical) monitoring and have been able to correlate some issues of performance with users' devices hitting serious and critical thermal values.

While there are various ways to include sleeps and waits to add artificial CPU load.  It's not obvious how to fit this into our algorithm and the scope of that investigation seems too much.

Is there a way to take a physical iOS device, connect to Xcode/debugger and trigger a throttling event and actually get the CPU to respond properly on the iOS device and throttle our apps performance.  Then we would have a much more exact reproduction locally.

Comment: Of course you can take physical iOS device and connect it to debugger. There is even CPU profiler in there.
What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Maybe put your phone in the microwave for a couple seconds, or in the oven, or boil it a bit. The new iPhones are waterproof, right?

Comment: I have been at companies where we physically heat up the iPad on a heating plate (3D Printer, etc...).  However, this type of testing is not ideal.  If you do it too much, the device shuts down (too overheated).  Either way, this is not an ideal testing environment.

Regarding CPU Profiling, we have seen instances where the algorithm was using a more powerful cpu core, and then it wasn't.  We saw performance take a hit for a bit.  However, we don't know how to trigger this artificially to isolate this event.